# Testing each line in a file

Tags: python, file, testing

I am trying to write a Python program that reads each line from an infile. This infile is a list of dates. I want to test each line with a function isValid(), which returns true if the date is valid, and false if it is not. If the date is valid, it is written into an output file. If it is not, invalid is written into the output file. I have the function, and all I want to know is the best way to test each line with the function. I know this should be done with a loop, I'm just uncertain how to set up the loop to test each line in the file one-by-one.

Edit: I now have a program that basically works. However, I am getting incorrect output to the output file. Perhaps someone will be able to explain why.

Ok, I now have a program that basically works, but I'm getting strange results in the output file. Hopefully those with Python 3 experience can help.

```
   def main():
datefile = input("Enter filename: ")
t = open(datefile, "r")
c = t.readlines()
ofile = input("Enter filename: ")
o = open(ofile, "w")



for line in c:
    b = line.split("/")
    e = b[0]
    f = b[1]
    g = b[2]

    text = str(e) + " " + str(f) + ", " + str(g)
    text2 = "The date " + text + " is invalid"

    if isValid(e,f,g) == True:
        o.write(text)

    else:
        o.write(text2)



def isValid(m, d, y):
if m == 1 or m == 3 or m == 5 or m == 7 or m == 8 or m == 10 or m == 12:
    if d is range(1, 31):
        return True
elif m == 2:
    if d is range(1,28):
        return True
elif m == 4 or m == 6 or m == 9 or m == 11:
    if d is range(1,30):
        return True
else:
    return False
```

This is the output I'm getting.

The date 5 19, 1998
 is invalidThe date 7 21, 1984
 is invalidThe date 12 7, 1862
 is invalidThe date 13 4, 2000
 is invalidThe date 11 40, 1460
 is invalidThe date 5 7, 1970
 is invalidThe date 8 31, 2001
 is invalidThe date 6 26, 1800
 is invalidThe date 3 32, 400
 is invalidThe date 1 1, 1111
 is invalid

Answer (score 2):

In the most recent versions of Python you can use the context management features that are implicit for files:

```
results = list()
with open(some_file) as f:
    for line in f:
        if isValid(line, date):
            results.append(line)
```

... or even more tersely with a list comprehension:

```
with open(some_file) as f:
    results = [line for line in f if isValid(line, date)]
```

For progressively older versions of Python you might need to explicitly open and close the file (with simple implicit iteration over the file *for line in file:*) or add more explicit iteration over the file (*f.readline()* or *f.readlines()* (plural) depending on whether you want to "slurp" in the entire file (with the memory overhead implications of that) or iterate line-by-line).

Also note that you may wish to strip the trailing newlines off these file contents (perhaps by calling *line.rstrip('\n')* --- or possibly just *line.strip()* if you want to eliminate all leading and trailing whitespace from each line).

(Edit based on additional comment to previous answer):

The function signature **isValid(m,d,y)** suggests that you're passing a data to this function (month, day, year) but that doesn't make sense given that you must also, somehow, pass in the data to be validated (a line of text, a string, etc).

To help you further you'll have to provide more information (preferable the source or a relevant portion of the source to this "isValid()" function.

In my initial answer I was assuming that your "isValid()" function was merely scanning for any valid date in its single argument.  I've modified my code examples to show how one might pass a specific date, as a single argument, to a function which used this calling signature: "isValid(somedata, some_date)."

Comment: By the way, my code doesn't handle the case where the attempt to open "some_file" fails for whatever reason.  You'd have to wrap the `with` statement and its suite with `try:`...`except EnvironmentError:` exception handling if you wanted to gracefully handle that sort of problem.  (The implicit handling of a file context manager will ensure that the file is closed after the end of the loop, regardless of any exceptions raised *after* the file was successfully opened, but does nothing about the failure to open).

Comment: To all those kind enough to answer and provide help, I've updated my OP with some code that's basically working, but I'm getting strange output. Any more help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open(fname) as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        test(line)
```

Comment: Why would you even call `readlines()` when you can iterate over `f` directly, saving memory?

Comment: The function I'm trying to use is isValid(m,d,y). How do I make this test work in main with your method? Do I need to analyze each line in the file so that the first character in each line = m, the next is d, and so on?

Comment: @BreckODonnell: You need to create another function, `convert_string_to_date()`, which parses the input text into a date of the `m, d, y` format.

Comment: To all those kind enough to answer and provide help, I've updated my OP with some code that's basically working, but I'm getting strange output. Any more help would be appreciated.